# Error : An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework.

I have searched on this site and on google before asking this question and everywhere I found different answers. But my problem is not solved, so I am asking this question.

I get the above mentioned error while I try to delete a record.

Here is my code:

```
using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())


{

     var HaemogramsCorrespondingToPatient = (from h in db.Haemograms
                                             join m in db.MasterPatientHaemograms
                                             on h.HaemogramID equals m.HaemogramID
                                             where m.PatientID == SelectedPatient.PatientID
                                             select h);
     foreach (Haemogram haemogram in HaemogramsCorrespondingToPatient)
     {
          if (db.Entry(haemogram).State == System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
              db.Haemograms.Attach(haemogram);
          db.Haemograms.Remove(haemogram);
          db.Entry(haemogram).State = EntityState.Deleted;
     }

     var entry = db.Entry(SelectedPatient);
     if (entry.State == System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
         db.Patients.Attach(SelectedPatient); //I get error here
     db.Patients.Remove(SelectedPatient);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is the relationship between the tables:

[image]

**Note: Please note that Cascade delete is on in sql server.**

**Edit**

I have also noticed something strange.

When I create a patient and then try to delete the `CurrentPatient` object using the above mentioned code, I get the above mentioned error.

But when I create a patient and then restart the program and then I try to delete the `CurrentPatient` object, then it is deleted without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only imagine that this error occurs if `SelectedPatient` contains referenced objects of type `MasterPatientHaemogram` and these again referenced objects of type `Haemogram`. When you attach `SelectedPatient` (which is apparently a detached entity) the whole object graph will be attached including `Haemogram` objects with possibly the same key that you already have loaded in the query for `HaemogramsCorrespondingToPatient`. This would cause the exception.

Simplest and safest solution is not to try to attach the detached `SelectedPatient` at all but load a copy from the database and delete this entity instead:

```
//...
var patient = db.Patients.Find(SelectedPatient.PatientID);
db.Patients.Remove(patient);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If you dislike to query the database with `Find` create a stub entity with just the correct key:

```
//...
var patient = new Patient { PatientID = SelectedPatient.PatientID };
db.Patients.Attach(patient);
db.Patients.Remove(patient);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I have tried to use your code1 in my project. Now I get another error.
The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

Comment: @Khushi: Did you really use `db.Patients.Remove(patient)`, **NOT** `db.Patients.Remove(SelectedPatient)`?